# Trajectory equation of a reastic falling paper

Tags: game-physics, physics-engine

I'm trying to implement this animation in libGDX and I'm trying to come  up with the proper animation equation that will mimic a realistic  falling paper trajectory

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3_nxyQoYw8

I my equation now contain the gravitational acceleration and I move it in a random spiral to the board z-position..

but I can't integrate the complete set of physical parameters that should be there in real world like the drag force that slows it down , or the random wind direction..

Do you have any ideas abut that?

Comment: Please recheck your youtube link....it seems to be broken